# backbone.js + require.js + user authentication

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Started learning backbone.js and require.js.

Not sure how to structure files for web app with user authentication.

Seems it should flow like this:

1. On app init, query server to check auth session state;

   - Q#1: where should I be writing this 'after init' session code - in /js/app.js?
   - Q#2: should I be using jQuery ajax for this, or is there better backbone.js methods (I've seen references to get(), fetch(), toJSON() in examples)?
2. If success, store auth data in a model (user_id, username, auth_token).

   - Q#3: how/where do I init this model so that I can access that data throughout modules? ie. I will have a view to display template for 'isLoggedIn.html' that will read "Hello %username%! Logout". I want to access 'username' field from this model. Currently, I see only how to create a new model by referencing it in the view's define[], so I don't know how to access the model that was created during init.
3. Will use jQuery $.cookies to save and get this auth data, so if user leaves page and returns, I can query server to check session instead of requiring user to login again.

   - Q#4: how do I include jquery.cookies.js plugin into this requirejs app, so that I can later use $.cookies as usual? Am I supposed to add this plugin to the define[] list? Do I have to add it to the /js/jquery/loader.js file?

Thank you for your assistance.

**Edit:** I used the files from [modular-backbone](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/modular-backbone) example to create my web app. So when I am talking about /js/app.js and js/router.js, that's the files I refer to.

Comment: For Q3: can't you create the user model and then pass it around to the relevant views when you construct those views?

Comment: Also, what do you mean you can only create a new model when referencing it in define?  Post a snippet of that model's code?

Comment: I'm using the structure from modular-backbone. So in my app.js I'm creating `var credentials = new authModel()`. From what I understand, I then have to access this `credentials` var in the login view. But credentials isn't a global variable, so in the login view credentials is null - don't see any of the data.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same situation as well.
I found [this post](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/) and it seems like the best option to do something before every request is to use [this solution](https://github.com/angelo0000/backbone_filters).

Before accessing and URL except /login, I'm going to authenticate by cookie or run the login view.

About the way to include other folders (jQuery cookie)- just use the require.js mechanism:

1. In your main file 'require.config' -> 'paths' add the plugin location (jqueryCokkie:)
2. In your view under 'define' add the path name ('jqueryCookie') and pass it to the finction
3. The .js file should be in the [following structure](http://pastecode.com/Nl) (I tried to paste the code example here, but got problems...).