# User Login using Backbonejs

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, backbone.js, slim

I am trying to develop an application using Backbonejs and SLIM php framework. Now I need to develop a user login. I read several posts in stackoverflow. Some of them are

[How can I deny users access to parts of my Backbone App if they have not logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981975/how-can-i-deny-users-access-to-parts-of-my-backbone-app-if-they-have-not-logged?lq=1)

[Backbone.js Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031481/backbone-js-security?rq=1)

[Backbone.js and user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359497/backbone-js-and-user-authentication)

[backbone.js + require.js + user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676714/backbone-js-require-js-user-authentication?rq=1)

[backbone.js - handling if a user is logged in or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808655/backbone-js-handling-if-a-user-is-logged-in-or-not/5837057#5837057)

I would like to know which is the appropriate and secure process/way in this regard ??

Comment: each question is very broad. this question is a very large topic. I'm not sure this is going to survive moderation.

Comment: use whatever suits you and you're comfortable with, it'll evolve with time ;) of course don't be afraid to refactor

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first comment this is a very broad topic. For a real application I'd recommend finding a solution that already exists and incorporating it into your project (there is a lot that can go wrong). I cannot give you many recommendations, but I have used [UserCake](http://usercake.com) with Slim successfully. I've read about, but not used, other authentication systems that use Slim's middleware. I'd think you would want to find one that fits your needs, probably one that can handle AJAX with your Backbone front end.

On the other hand building your own can be an educational experience. I did it once in [plain PHP](https://github.com/deplicator/UserAuthenticationSystem) (warning do not use that project) just to appreciate solutions that already exist. I gained a better understanding of salting, hashing, sql injection and security in general.